# css responsive design table height not taken into account

Tags: css

I have a two-column responsive layout with an HTML table at the bottom of the left column. At certain width `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)`, the right column is repositioned beneath the left one. Then it seems as the table height is not calculated properly and there is overlap between the table and the top of the second (right) column. Is there a way to fix this in CSS? Other minor problems I have is centering the images vertically and the table horizontally in their parent containers without using flexbox technology

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}
img {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 border: 1px dashed crimson;
}
#wm-container {
 height: 95%;
 background-color: black;
 padding: 0.5%;
}
#wm-inf {
 background-color: lavender;
 margin: 0.5%;
 padding: 0.5%;
}
#wm-left {
 float: left;
 width: 49%;
 height: 90%;
 background-color: Silver;
 padding: 0.5%;
}
#wm-right {
 float: right;
 width: 48%;
 height: 90%;
 background-color: Silver;
 padding: 0.5%;
}
#wm-main {
 text-align: center;
 height: 65%;
 background-color: lavender;
 border: 1px dotted black;
 padding: 0.5%;
}
#wm-score-tbl {
 text-align: center;
 height: 30%;
 background-color: lavender;
 border: 1px dotted black;
 padding: 0.5%;
}
#wm-a4c {
 text-align: center;
 height: 55%;
 width: 57%;
 padding-left: 0.5%;
 float: left;
 border: 1px dotted black;
 background-color: lavender;
 padding: 0.5%;
}
#wm-a2c {
 text-align: center;
 height: 55%;
 width: 38%;
 padding-left: 0.5%;
 float: left;
 border: 1px dotted black;
 background-color: lavender;
 padding: 0.5%;
}
#wm-a3c {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 height: 40%;
 width: 97%;
 padding-left: 0.5%;
 border: 1px dashed black;
 background-color: rgba(230,230,250,0.5);
 padding: 0.5%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#wm-left, #wm-right {
 float: none;
 width: auto;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="wm-container"> 
 <div id="wm-inf">wm-inf</div>
 <div id="wm-left">
  <div id="wm-main"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/480/"></div>
  <div id="wm-score-tbl">
   <table border="1px solid #dddddd">
    <tr>
     <th>Entry Header 1</th>
     <th>Entry Header 2</th>
     <th>Entry Header 3</th>
     <th>Entry Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Entry First Line 1</td>
     <td>Entry First Line 2</td>
     <td>Entry First Line 3</td>
     <td>Entry First Line 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Entry Line 1</td>
     <td>Entry Line 2</td>
     <td>Entry Line 3</td>
     <td>Entry Line 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Entry Line 1</td>
     <td>Entry Line 2</td>
     <td>Entry Line 3</td>
     <td>Entry Line 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Entry Line 1</td>
     <td>Entry Line 2</td>
     <td>Entry Line 3</td>
     <td>Entry Line 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Entry Line 1</td>
     <td>Entry Line 2</td>
     <td>Entry Line 3</td>
     <td>Entry Line 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Entry Last Line 1</td>
     <td>Entry Last Line 2</td>
     <td>Entry Last Line 3</td>
     <td>Entry Last Line 4</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="wm-right">
  <div id="wm-a3c"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/"></div>
  <div id="wm-a4c"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/640/"></div>
  <div id="wm-a2c"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/640/"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

.